# How do I use form names in Angular to get input data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

In this tutorial by [Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/forms.html), he asserts that you can give a form a name, and then access it in the controller by

```
$scope.FORM_NAME.INPUT_NAME
```

For example like

```
<form name="myFormNg" ng-submit="myForm.submitTheForm()" >
    <input name="firstName" type="text" ng-model="myForm.firstName">
  </form>
```

and then in Angular

```
$scope.myFormNg.firstName
```

However, when I try it, instead of getting what I typed into the input box (`abc`), I get this whole object:

```
{"$viewValue":"abc","$modelValue":"abc","$$rawModelValue":"abc","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":false,"$touched":true,"$pristine":false,"$dirty":true,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$error":{},"$$success":{"parse":true,"required":true},"$name":"email","$options":null,"$$lastCommittedViewValue":"abc"}
```

Why? Is there a cleaner way to do it that Jenkov omits?

Comment: Why not just access it through scope with your "myForm.firstName" model property?

Comment: the object "myForm" contains your input ... try console.log($scope.myForm) in your  controller

Comment: @Chris I thought naming the form is the more proper way

Comment: Jenkov is using the form name to check if a form field is valid. If you only need to get the values use $scope.myForm.firstName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Jenkov mentions (and quite clearly) one thing: with `$scope.formName.inputName` you'll get an instance of `ngModelController` (and only if this input is already bound - with `ng-model` or in some other way).

This instance has many uses; you can get back its view value (via $viewValue property; see this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7p09tbe5/)), check whether or not it passes validation etc. - but it's still an Object, not a string.

Comment: I missed that, sorry. Thank you!